# Close BufferedImage so I can delete it?

Tags: java

I have opened an image using `ImageIO.read(File file)` function and it returned the `BufferedImage`. I read the pixels from that image, and now I want to delete it from file system. The problem is that `file.delete()` returns `false`. Call to the `Files.delete(file.toPath())` throws an exception:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: C:\<file_location>\1517053169520.png: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

I've shortened the path for the sake of readability.

Here's the code snippet:

```
public void test (File file) {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
    byte[] pixels = ((DataBufferByte)image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
    // I do a bunch of things here, but I don't modify the pixels
    image.flush();

    /* I tried this too, but I know that GC doesn't have to be called immediately when I make a call to System.gc()

    image = null;
    System.gc();

    */

    Files.delete(file.toPath());
}
```

So, my question is: How can I release the file, so that it can be deleted?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wanted to simplify the code, but I forgot to edit that too. It should be `file`. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an [issue reported some time ago with a similar scenario](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7166379). The following snippet should solve the issue by releasing the stream:

```
BufferedImage image = null;
InputStream stream = null;
try {
    stream = new FileInputStream(file);
    image = ImageIO.read(stream);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error("Image could not be read: "+file);

} finally {
    if (stream != null) {
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error("ERROR closing image input stream: "+ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

@kekec shows the good idea implemented with an obsolete construct. Starting with Java7 you can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) which simplifies the code above (below, who knows) to:

```
BufferedImage image = null;
try(FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file)){
    image = ImageIO.read(stream);
}
```

And of course you can decide to catch the Exception, or let it get thrown outwards.